# Grails "don't flush the Session after an exception occurs" error message

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

I see that this error message has been posted several times already in the context of hibernate.

I am getting this error while using grails service and a domain class, any help will be really appreciated

Domain class

```
class Coupon {
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    String code
    String email
    String address
    String state
    String city
    String zip
    def couponCodeGeneratorService

    def beforeValidate() {
        println code+"---------8-"
        code = couponCodeGeneratorService.generate()
        println code+"----------"
    }
    static constraints = {
        email blank:false,email:true
        address blank:false
        state blank:false
        city blank:false
        zip blank:false
    }
}
```

Service

```
class CouponCodeGeneratorService {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random()
    def serviceMethod() {

    }
    def generate(){
        def group1 =  randomGenerator.nextInt(9999)+"";
        def group2 =  randomGenerator.nextInt(9999)+"";
        def group3 =  randomGenerator.nextInt(9999)+"";
        def group4 =  randomGenerator.nextInt(9999)+"";
        return group1.padLeft(4,"0") +group2.padLeft(4,"0")+group3.padLeft(4,"0")+group4.padLeft(4,"0")
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
---------8-
4844634041715590----------
4844634041715590---------8-
| Error 2012-09-10 11:32:54,938 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in com.easytha.Coupon entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
   Line | Method
->>  19 | beforeValidate     in com.easytha.Coupon
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    46 | onApplicationEvent in org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener
|    24 | save . . . . . . . in com.easytha.CouponController
|   186 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|    63 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   886 | runTask            in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . . . . .  in     ''
^   662 | run                in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2012-09-10 11:32:54,944 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - AssertionFailure occurred when processing request: [POST] /EasyTha/coupon/save - parameters:
zip: asdf
address: asd
email: s.s@s.xom
state: asd
code: 
create: Create
city: asdf
null id in com.easytha.Coupon entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs). Stacktrace follows:
Message: null id in com.easytha.Coupon entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
   Line | Method
->>  19 | beforeValidate     in com.easytha.Coupon
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    46 | onApplicationEvent in org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener
|    24 | save . . . . . . . in com.easytha.CouponController
|   186 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|    63 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   886 | runTask            in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . . . . .  in     ''
^   662 | run                in java.lang.Thread
```

I am not very familiar with Hibernate, also is this a correct way to create a coupon code that looks like a credit card number?

Comment: Sounds like it could be failing validation or the service throws an exception but the code that is calling save on the domain still tries to call save(), can you try checking for that?

Comment: @steve The controller has only 'scaffold = true' annotation. I added try catch in the service method and now the exception looks a little bit different. Now, the console prints the debug messages before and after calling the service method. Please see the updated exception

Comment: So that is saying 'code' is empty and it shouldn't be so its failing validation and I think thats why you see the error, can you go back and just hardcode a value for 'code' in the beforeValidate()...sorry if I am misleading it is a bit of a guess at this point

Comment: @Steve, nope... same error even if I send the code value... and anyways validation should not occur before "beforevalidate" gets called correct? and after it being called the code string has a value!

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea calling a _transactional_ service method from inside `beforeValidate`, I wouldn't be surprised if the transaction logic is inserting an extra flush or triggering an extra validate at an inappropriate moment.  Try adding `static transactional = false` to `CouponCodeGeneratorService`.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks a lot Ian, it worked!! Can you convert you comment to an answer! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem may be that the `CouponCodeGeneratorService` is transactional.  Therefore, when you call the service method from inside your `beforeValidate` you're opening and closing a transaction (even though you don't touch the database inside the method), which among other things will cause another flush of the session.

Try making the service non-transactional:

```
static transactional = false
```

Comment: Nice one.  I don't even see the point of having this method inside a service anyway?  might be cleaner in a static Util class or a Mixin?